# How to fix No Such File Or Directory Error message while using SCP Command

Tags: server, ssh, scp

I want to transfer file from Server to my local machine through SSH Connection.

But i am getting No such file or directory error message.

i have file following path: File Name is messageSentLog.log

```
[root@appsrvr1 ~]# cd tomcat7_640_CS
[root@appsrvr1 tomcat7_640_CSS]# cd logs
[root@appsrvr1 logs]# scp tomcat7_640_CS/logs/messageSentLog.log Ashokkkumar Muthu@10.8.51.40:D/temp
```

No responses.

Please help me to overcome from this issue

Comment: your path is incorrect.  `scp messageSentLog.log root@localhost:/dest/dir`. You already in the directory and your destination is malform.

Answer (score 0):

1. `Ashokkkumar Muthu` isn't your username. Use your username, maybe `Ashok`
2. Your path is wrong. You're already in `tomcat7_640_CS/logs`
3. And the target? Maybe you have a folder with the name `D` in your home folder…

Therefore

```
scp messageSentLog.log ashok@10.8.51.40:D/temp
```

But I suspect the target system is not a Linux system.